# Quantifying amount of sunlight falling in a region

Tags: dem, geography

I am trying to objectively quantify or provide some form of indication that could point toward the amount of sunlight

Anyone knows if there are any datasets (either instrumental or remotely sensed data) or derivational approaches that provides such information on the amount of sunlight received?

Comment: What software do you have? If ArcGIS+Spatial Analyst you can use the [Solar Radiation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000t8000000) toolset. There are also QGIS+[GRASS](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.sun.html)/[SAGA](https://darrenwiens.wordpress.com/tag/solar-radiation/) approaches

Comment: thats great ! I shall attempt to do that